# Make my Rails App work with 1GB on Linode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memory, cpu-usage

Until I applied caching my Rails app was very slow running it locally on my notebook. Yesterday I deployed the app to my Linode 1024 for the first time and clearly it's too slow.

Now I don't know whether this is due to 1x CPU priority or really a memory issue. The application is not responsive at all, of course after the first request it works more or less okay.

What can I do to optimize this? Precalculated even more values and store them in the database? How does one handle this if there is few CPU priority and even fewer memory?

Comment: what web server are you running? I run very intensive apps on 512MB of RAM with 1x CPU just fine.  You said it is also running slow on your local machine?

Comment: @NoahDavis Apache. I heard nginx has a lower footprint due to its event-based architecture, but it shouldn't make a different for single requests, should it? It runs okayish locally, especially after the first requests I would say it is fast.

Comment: I would strongly suggest switching over to NGINX, there's a great railscast episdoe for deploying to Linode using NGINX, Unicorn and Capistrano (http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) and with this tutorial, I've never had a single issue getting a rails app to run a VPS super efficiently.

Comment: Thank you Noah, much appreciated. Also feel free to add this as an answer. My question is pretty broad, so I am lucky it did not got downvoted yet, but the resources are very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest switching over to NGINX, there's a great railscast episdoe for deploying to Linode using NGINX, Unicorn and Capistrano (railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) and with this tutorial, I've never had a single issue getting a rails app to run a VPS super efficiently. In my experience running an app with Apache always results in slower query times, especially under higher traffic.

[Railscast #335](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps)